# What happens if you do not call the function again at the end of a receive block? - Erlang

Tags: erlang

An example of this would be:

```
myFunction()
   receive 
      msg1 -> io:format("Message 1!~n"),
              self() ! msg1,
              myFunction();
      msg2 -> io:format("Message 2!~n")
end.
```

I learnt to do my messages like msg1; but recently I made an error and compiled my code similar to msg2. When msg2 occurs, what happens afterwards? Does the process just sit at that same receive after msg2 and wait for other messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't call the function again at the end of a receive block, the process will die.(if you case, if you send `msg2` to the process), but if you send other message(except for `msg1` and `msg2`), the process will wait, and the messages are stored in the process's message queue.

```
-module(wy).
-compile(export_all).

myFunction() ->
receive 
    msg1 -> 
        io:format("Message 1!~n"),
        self() ! msg1,
        myFunction();
    msg2 -> 
        io:format("Message 2!~n")
end.
parent() ->
    Pid = spawn(fun myFunction/0),
    register(myFunction, Pid),
    erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
    receive
        Res -> io:format("Receive ~p~n", [Res])
    end.

main() ->
    spawn(fun() -> parent() end).
```

first you need execute `wy:main().`

(1) if you execute `myFunction ! msg22.`, you can find the process `myFunction` is still alive, and use this command `erlang:process_info(whereis(myFunction), messages).`, you can find the message `msg22` is stored in the message queue.

(2) if you execute `myFunction ! msg2.`, you can get this output

```
Message 2!
Receive {'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.0.108>,process,<0.48.0>,normal}
msg2
```

from this output you can know the process `myFunction` is died.

(3) if you execute `myFunction ! msg1`, the process will go into endless loop。

Answer (score 4):

*Why don't you try it yourself?*

If you don't call the function after receiving `msg2`, then there is nothing more to execute and your process will quit.

> Does the process just sit at that same receive after msg2 and wait for other messages?

No. You need to call the function again. The recursion creates a loop.

> When msg2 occurs, what happens afterwards?

`Message 2!\n` is printed and `myFunction/0`'s code is no longer executed, and if the current process has nothing more to do it exits.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are almost correct. If you don't do a recursive call after receiving `msg2` then the function will end and you will go back to the caller of `myFunction/0`. It will then depend on the caller what happens. If this is the last thing to do in the process then the process will terminate with reason `normal`, otherwise it will continue processing.

The thing to remember is that each call to `receive` will just process one message so if you want to keep processing messages then you must do repeated calls to `receive`. Hence the recursion in `myFunction`.